# Resource png not found

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-7

i make a png resource file named **glyfs.rc**
`GLYF_CONFEDITOR RCDATA confeditor.png   GLYF_EXTRAFE RCDATA extrafe.png   .......`

i add it in my project.
Put a TsBitBtn (it is an [alphaskin](https://www.alphaskins.com/dwnld.php) component class)  and try to load the glyf from resource file
`sbitbtn1.Glyph.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance,'GLYF_CONFEDITOR');`
when i run i get the error resource file with name 'GLYF_CONFEDITOR' not found.

What am i doing wrong?

The 3 party tool i use for png is pngdelphi downloaded from [here](http://delphi.pjh2.de/articles/graphic/png.php)
But the sbitbtn loads native the png files...

Comment: (1) Did you compile the resource file? (2) Did you add the compiled resource file to the project?

Comment: In addition, Delphi 7 does not support PNG images (without 3rd-party code).

Comment: Andreas Rejbramd = 1 yes 2 yes

Comment: Yes i know i add a 3 party code...

Comment: I'm downvoting the question because you didn't tell us the true facts. How can anyone answer if you don't tell the truth about the components you use?

Comment: 1. Which PNG library you are using. 2. The class of bit button.

Comment: @azrael11: If you write `BitBtn` (or even `sBitBtn`), almost everyone will think you are talking about the `TBitBtn` class that is a part of the VCL. If you are using some other, 3rd-party component, like the Alphaskin control, you need to be very clear about that. You didn't meniton the word "Alphaskin", and you didn't mention the class `TsBitBtn`. By the phrase "Put a sBitBtn1..." you were talking about an *instance*, not a *class*, so it was a bit unclear.

Comment: @azrael11 You have the opportunity to edit your question and supply details that would be needed to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok i edit hope i give the full question now

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple problems with your code:

- `TBitBtn.Glyph` is of type `TBitmap` and `TBitmap.LoadFromResourceName` assumes `RT_BITMAP` resource type, not `RT_RCDATA`, hence "resource not found" error.
- Even if you use RT_BITMAP it will throw `EInvalidGraphic` or similar¹ because again - `TBitBtn.Glyph` is `TBitmap` and naturally TBitmap wont load PNG data.

¹ there is WinAPI function LoadImage behind LoadFromResourceName, actual error message may vary.